# How can i apply background-image to low div

Tags: html, css

Example, html code,

```
<div id="container_background">
    <div id="content">
        <p>
            #container
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container_background{
    background-image:url('main_bg.gif');
    height: 430px;
}
```

if i code like this, the background is applied to #container_background div, but not #content div.

how can i apply to #content either?

of course, background-image inside #content will not be an option, because the image has to be one connected image, but if i put this, it wont be connected.

Comment: do not understand properly. Do you mean that background image for #container_background div will be shown in the #content div too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this CSS:**

for `#container_background`:

```
#container_background{
    background-image:url('main_bg.gif');
    height: 430px;
}
```

for `#content`:

```
#content{
        background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add classes to your divs instead of identifiers like this:

```
.container-background .content {
     background:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Cross-Browser Transparency of css:

```
#content {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0;           /* fx, safari, opera */
    }
```